# How to count total number of days according to a condition?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following database structure:

```
DATE         AMOUNT      COUNTRY      CITY
12/02/2023    23.9        BRASIL     RIO DE JANEIRO
13/02/2023    3.9         BRASIL     RIO DE JANEIRO
14/02/2023    2.9         BRASIL     SAO PAULO
15/02/2023    10.0        BRASIL     CURITIBA
16/02/2023    71.3        BRASIL     CURITIBA
17/02/2023    22.2        PARAGUAY   ASUNCION

...
```

What I want to know is how many days I've been in every country. For example:

DAYS SPEND IN BRASIL

```
3
```

Right now, I'm not able to paste code that I'm using because I've been trying different solutions related to QUERY, DATEDIFF... but at the end I couldn't find the solution.

I'm asking this solution because I don't want to use manual filters from the table.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in cell A1 you don't need any query stuff, you can use a plain formula in a new column:

```
=MAXIFS(A:A,C:C,C2)-MINIFS(A:A,C:C,C2)
```

if you want to put this in summary format next to a country you can replace C:C with the cell where you country is and it will work like that as well.

Comment: thanks for your anwer man. So helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=query(unique(filter({C2:C,A2:A},A2:A<>"")),"Select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'COUNTRY', count(Col2) 'DAYS_SPENT'")
```

[image]